# How to install 'main menu' by using only terminal?

Tags: 13.04, menu

My Software Centre has crashed. Then I don't have any other ways to install packages.
Please tell me how to install main menu (editor) using the terminal. I need main menu (editor) for editing my menu and installing other softwares in my Ubuntu 13.04 desktop.

Comment: Your questions are confusing. How did `Software Center` crash? What does it do when you run it? What editor are you referring to? `gedit` should be installed already. What are you trying to edit? What were you doing that caused this?

Comment: Editing the main menu will not help you, it is not displayed under Unity.

Comment: @Marc
I was trying to install Mainmenu editor application which is commonly used for editing and rearranging menu items.
But when I try to do it, The software center isn't working anyway.
Its just opened.
But When I clicked the Install now button, It seems to be crashed and dimmed the entire Software center window !
Please Tell me what to do  !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You **can** install the *menu editor* from command line with

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install alacarte
```

As I said in my comment, that will not enable you to install software in a graphical mode.

You **should** fix the problem you have with Ubuntu Software Center - I suppose you will run into some error when you execute above commands. If yes edit your question to show us eventual error messages.